# Q_PROPERTIES vs signal/connection and common enum in QML and C++

Tags: c++, qt, enums

I will not pass any complete code sample for this discussion.

We are having a discussion here regarding the use of Q_PROPERTIES in a c++ defined QT model vs passing signals with parameters between c++ and qml.

A project with several hundred buttons (and analog gauges) to interact from Quick to c++ will be the result. Also the intention is to create a simple c++ frontend part with Qt, this will emit messages via another message handler system using same type enums as received from QML and then passed to backend. Backend without Qt.

The model is created as a context property.

Option 1:
Define Q_PROPTERTY for every variable to be passed in between. Notify makes an emit, changes value, QML can read and use the new value...

looking at the MOC files, I can spot quite a few switch/case both ways actually, both in emit and in receiving part.

Believe the simplified nature in terms of common enums and less code in option 2, does not really add additional resource consumption.

Option 2:
Define generic signals in c++, this passed enum values, also defined as Q_ENUM. Hence we can switch/case it in the QML files to use the values, direct function call from QML to C++:

C++ signal:

```
void qmlValueNotifier(int enumid, int enumvalue);
void qmlStatusNotifier(int enumid, bool enumstatus);
```

QML connection, multiple places

```
Connections {
        target: globalControl
        onQmlValueNotifier: {
            switch (enumid){
            case Global.SOMEVALUE1:
                someproperty1 = enumvalue
                break;
            case Global.SOMEVALUE2:
                someproperty2 = enumvalue
                break;
            case Global.SOMEVALUE3:
                someproperty3 = enumvalue
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question? SO is made for specific questions.

Comment: It's pretty hard formulating a question directly. The question could be: Using 100 Q_PROPERTY in a model. I believe every request to the same object (context property) will trigger the same "switch case" to be run in (cpp moc file) every time a QML is reading a value. Also other way around when a change notification is triggered from c++ a switch case is run.  Alternatively, adding a signal to be "Connected" in qml, it will render a JavaScript function to be run in QML. Will the signal/JavaScript approach be less efficient than the Q_PROPERTY approach

Comment: I prefer to create a model with roles instead of QObjects with Q_Property

Comment: We've used AbstractUITableItemModel with roles for something else in the project. For actual lists. But offcourse we can perhaps index using the enums and do direct lookup. Will explore it and post possible results. The negative side of using signals to update button status and other bar values via JavaScript in QML opposed to properties is if we destroy and re-create a QML object. Then it has to query the c++ part for status update again to retrieve correct values. But that works also as a separate function call upon completed

Comment: I would use `Q_PROPERTY` as it results in less/easier user code. Small performance differences are not an issue in this situation.